# Matlab: Search for center of objects in binary image

Tags: image, matlab, object, image-processing, binary

I have an image like the following:

[image: binary img]

It's plotted via `imshow(I)` and `I` is a logical matrix, you can get this one from here:
http://pastebin.com/qsxA0GXy

Those objects are mostly something like a rough circle, but they also can be some sort of eliptic of about three times greater in size.

I want to find the coordinates of the center of those objects, but only estimated. I dont want to use a circular hough transform as I need only a estimated value and I need a fast algorithm.

My idea was: Loop each pixel and if it's a `true` value, search all neighboor-pixel which are also `true` and than get the center of the object by calculating

> x = x_max - xmin;
>
> y = y_max - ymin;

but I dont like this approach as it seems quite slow for me with using 2 nested for loops.
Anything nicer you can think of?
thanks!

Comment: If you use `bwtraceboundary` you can trace the objects in your binary image. Then once you catch the object, you can do a [pixel based like tihs](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/252880) Here is another great approach you could [implement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242120/detecting-center-point-of-cross-using-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be quite fast. Not too sure how it'll scale though:

```
L = bwlabel(I);
stats = regionprops(L,I,'Centroid');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the concept used in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2242565/845528

I tried it (by saving the image you have provided above. I didn't go to the link you provided). It seems to work:

```
    Image = imread('im.jpg');
    dImage = im2double(Image);
    logicalImage = im2bw(dImage, 0.5);

    dilatedImage = bwmorph(logicalImage, 'shrink',Inf);
    [x,y] = find(dilatedImage);
```

Comment: wow I really love the trick using morphological shrinking, but its quite slow I'm afraid. For my whole image 1000x1000 pixels it takes like 2secs :( Not that good for "real time" usage

Comment: Ha, I had some "weird" noise objects around the objects I want the centers of... When removing the noise manually, it works super fast since the algorithmn probably doesnt have to run that often. Thanks a lot, very cute approach! And working like a charm!

Comment: This is a wrong approach to the problem, it makes no sense to use morphological shrinking for this -- you must assume that your objects will never have holes. If you happen to ever have a noise that causes any kind of hole, i.e., a single dark point at least, in your binary objects then the result you get with this approach is meaningless. Please check the answer provided by @Geodesic.